# .Net Core 2.1 Console Application Referencing .Net Framework 4.6.1 DLL - Possible?

Tags: dll, console-application, .net-framework-version, .net-core-2.1

Is it even possible for a .Net Core 2.1 console application to reference a .Net Framework 4.6.1 DLL?

I have such a DLL that consumes a WCF service successfully. I now wish to use this DLL from a .Net Core 2.1 console application. But I am getting an exception stating that it cannot load assembly System.ServiceModel. The web.config file in the 4.6.1 DLL has relevant settings for System.ServiceModel.

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't mind if you down vote me. But please do share your thoughts.